# How do I convert a clock in one time domain to another?

Tags: time, system, clock

I have two devices running independently. I have access to a clock query routine on device A, and I receive data from device A. Each data packet is timestamped with a tick count from device A.

I would like to convert the timestamp of each received packet into the time domain of device B. I do this by sampling and building a simple linear model between the two clocks using the query routine. The process looks like this:

```
for i in range(0,sampleCount):
  start = deviceA.timenow()
  sampleB = deviceB.timenow()
  end = deviceA.timenow()

  sampleA = start + 0.5 * (end - start)
  modelbuilder.step(sampleA, sampleB)
```

This is logical in my head, but in practice I find a constant delta between the modelled values and reality.

My question is, how do I convert times from one device, into the time domain of a device running on a different clock?

Comment: 1) How do you know there is "a constant delta?" 2) What language is this? 3) Is this code running on device A, device B, both, neither, or something else?

Comment: I'm not sure this is a software problem, you might have better luck on electronics.SE

Comment: @BumsBA this is a software problem. Hardware could solve it, but hardware won't be solving it in my case. In theory it should be possible to model the relationship, given that it is likely a simple linear relationship.

Comment: I'm using C++. The code above is psuedo-code.

Comment: oi, I didn't mean to imply this should be fixed with hardware, just that there are system considerations affecting what's going on. Anyways, I think there's some latency issues you're not taking into consideration. I might start with looking at how NTP handles the problem: http://www.ntp.org/ntpfaq/NTP-s-algo.htm